# Case Insensitive List Filtering

Tags: jquery, html

I'm trying to filter a list without worrying about whether a word is capitalized or not.

I have the following HTML:

```
<ul class="dropdown-menu gatherDropDown" id="list">
   <h3 id="header">Filter by </h3>
   <input id="filter" type="text" name="fname" onkeyup="filterList(this)">
   <li><input type="checkbox" class="item_name"> Producer 1</li>
   <li><input type="checkbox" class="item_name"> Producer 2</li>
   <li><input type="checkbox" class="item_name"> Producer 3</li>
   <li><input type="checkbox" class="item_name"> Producer 4</li>
   <li><input type="checkbox" class="item_name"> Producer 5</li>
   <li><input type="checkbox" class="item_name"> Producer 6</li>
   <li><input type="checkbox" class="item_name"> Producer 7</li>
</ul>
```

Here is my jQuery:

```
function filterList(element){
  var value = $(element).val();

  $("#list > li:not(:contains(" + value + "))").hide();
  $("#list > li:contains(" + value + ")").show();
}
```

I have also set up a codepen: http://codepen.io/tetonhiker/pen/Nbqrzd

Comment: You've always an uppercase char at first place? If so, maybe something like that could help? https://codepen.io/Aer0/pen/GNJqzo

Comment: that works, but then once I remove any text from the input text area the original list doesn't show up. How could I have it show up again?

Comment: Side-remark: your HTML is invalid. You shouldn't have an `input` tag nor a `h3` tag immediately under a `ul` tag.

Comment: I know Mikey - just doing it for a project that has that all wrapped into a slide out menu using some old bootstrap. It still works fine, but I had to wrap it all together

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Well I've changed your js quite a bit but how about something like this (see the bottom for an explanation):

```js
$("#filter").on("keyup", function() {
 var value = $(this).val().toLowerCase();
 $("#list > li").each(function() {
  $(this).toggle( $(this).text().toLowerCase().indexOf(value) !== -1 )
 });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<h3 id="header">Filter by </h3>
<input id="filter" type="text" name="fname">
<ul class="dropdown-menu gatherDropDown" id="list">
  <li><input type="checkbox" class="item_name">Producer 1</li>
  <li><input type="checkbox" class="item_name">Producer 2</li>
  <li><input type="checkbox" class="item_name">Producer 3</li>
  <li><input type="checkbox" class="item_name">Producer 4</li>
  <li><input type="checkbox" class="item_name">Producer 5</li>
  <li><input type="checkbox" class="item_name">Producer 6</li>
  <li><input type="checkbox" class="item_name">Producer 7</li>
</ul>
```

**Explanation:** I'm looping through each of your list items and checking whether their `.text()` value has a match for the value of the `input` box. The reason it's not case sensitive is that it makes everything lower case.

Comment: Shorter to use [.toggle()](http://api.jquery.com/toggle/) instead of `show()` and `hide()`.

Comment: @Mikey .. yes an explanation would help rather than just saying what is shorter to us

Comment: @Teton-Coder no problem. But just to note, there is really no reason to have invalid HTML. I've corrected it in my answer. If you need it wrapped in something consider using a `div`.

Comment: @Teton-Coder also, this solution is fine when there are only 7 options. If you start going over 100 (maybe fewer even) you'll probably begin hitting performance problems. You should look into using something like React.

Comment: I'm not really familiar with React, but yes once I'm finished we will be pulling in a list from the db with more than a few hundred items. So react would be faster to do this with?

Comment: @Teton-Coder definitely. The trick is that you don't want to be doing these kinds of loops all over the place because they modify the DOM real time. You want to process all the DOM changes you need to make at the same time and then send that as a single change to the browser. React makes that easy (but it's got a learning curve which is probably a bit steep for you at this point).

Comment: @Teton-Coder Maybe you should try reading and figuring it out yourself. @jcuenod You can simply pass a boolean in .toggle() function e.g. `$(this).toggle( $(this).text().toLowerCase().indexOf(value) !== -1 )`

Answer (score 0):

you can use this also

```
$.expr[":"].Contains = $.expr.createPseudo(function (arg) {
            return function (elem) {
                return $(elem).text().toLowerCase().indexOf(arg.toLowerCase()) >= 0;
            };
        });
        function filterList(element) {
            var value = $(element).val();
            $("#list > li:not(:Contains(" + value + "))").hide();
            $("#list > li:Contains(" + value + ")").show();
        }
```